# Update Delta table based on condition from another table

Tags: apache-spark, merge, sql-update, delta-lake

I want to update the Delta table based on the condition it matches with another table.

below is my sql , and I want to convert it into delta update.

```sql
update emp set empid = (select emp_id from dept where empname="xyz") 
where emp.deptid in (select dept_id from emp where emp_dept="IT")
```

I tried something like this with merge statement:

```scala
emp.merge(dept, "emp.dept_id = dept.merge_id")
  .whenMatched()
  .updateExpr(Map("emp_id" -> "dept.emp_id"))
  .execute()
```

but now I'm stuck where I need to check if that `emp_id` having name as "xyz" and also wanted to check `dept_id` in where clause as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am also facing the same, need a conditional check like if source.c==null then pick c from target. Any help will be appreciated